# How to check if the AWS object exists using AWS CLI and object ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have the following AWS object ARN:

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:xxxxxxxx:loadbalancer/app/production-lambda-alb/yyyyyyyyyyyy
```

I need to check if the object exists using the AWS CLI. How to do it?

**UPD**

`production-lambda-alb` is `elb` of application type.

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-names production-lambda-alb
```

returns error:

> An error occurred (LoadBalancerNotFound) when calling the DescribeLoadBalancers operation: There is no ACTIVE Load Balancer named 'production-lambda-alb'

however it isn't true as I can see the `production-lambda-alb` balancer in active state in aws console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Application and Network Load you have to use elbv2.

You can use the following cli:

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-arns arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:xxxxxxxx:loadbalancer/app/production-lambda-alb/yyyyyyyyyyyy
```

If it exists it will return result, if not it will return the following:

```
An error occurred (LoadBalancerNotFound) when calling the DescribeLoadBalancers operation: One or more load balancers not found
```

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-load-balancers.html

Comment: I vote up, but still need answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case where elb is of `application` type. I noticed that it works well for elb of `classic` type but doesn't work for elb of `application` type.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can use `aws elbv2` for ALBs and NLBs. `aws elb` used for CLBs.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - I had issue with `elb`. Following with `elbv2` helped to list the available ELB ARNs -

```
aws \
--profile AWS_PROFILE_NAME \
--region AWS_REGION \
elbv2 \
describe-load-balancers \
--query 'LoadBalancers[].LoadBalancerArn' --output text
```